# remove the top blue in activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

how do I remove the top blue with the words ListviewTest?

[image]

```
enter code here




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/gray_light2">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/impostazioni" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"></ImageView>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/personListView" android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="438dp">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call requestWindowFeature in your activity...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

put

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

in 'activity' tag in manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Put `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` at the top of your `onCreate()` method of the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Either add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"` to the activity tag in the manifest or add:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

to the onCreate method of your activity.